# support optional chaining and nullish oprtor in nx.dev

Tags: reactjs, typescript, optional-chaining, nx.dev

At the **first** step I added
 `"typescript": "~3.7.5"`
and then I added 
 `"prettier": "1.19.1"`
and it should've been enough, but I still getting this error:

> 'optionalChaining' isn't currently enabled

so I tried to add 
 `"react-scripts": "3.3.0"`
and

`"@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.8.3"`

`"@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.8.3"`
but problem still remained,
I did it in my normal **CRA** app but I don't know how I can change the **babel** preset list in the **nx.dev** configuration.